# Questions on open set Cantor Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to show that each point in the Cantor space, $\prod_{i \in\mathbb{N}}\{0,1\}_i$ is a limit point.

But I am confused about what is the open set of the Cantor space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always in products endowed with the [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology), an open set is a union of basic open set. A basic open set is of the form $\prod_{i\in\def\N{\mathbf N}\N} U_i$, where every $U_i \subseteq \{0,1\}$ is open and for all but finitely many $i\in \N$ we have $U_i = \{0,1\}$.

That is: A set $U \subseteq \prod_{i\in\N} \{0,1\}$ is open, iff for every $x \in U$ there is a finite set $I \subseteq \N$ such that for all $y\in \prod_{i\in \N} \{0,1\}$ with $x_i = y_i$ for all $i \in I$ we have $y \in U$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a point $x = (a_0, a_1, \ldots) \in \prod_{i \in\mathbb{N}}\{0,1\}_i$, the sequence
$$
x_n = (a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}, 1-a_n, 1-a_{n+1}, \ldots)
$$
will converge to $x$, without ever being equal to $x$, privong that $x$ is a limit point.

Proof of convergence: Let $U \ni x$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$. Then $U$ is of the form
$$
\prod_{i = 0}^\infty U_i
$$
where finitely many of the $U_i$ are equal to $\{a_i\}$, and the rest are equal to $\{1, 0\}$. This is what the product topology is: only finitely many components of an open set may be something other than the whole space of that component. In our case it means only finitely many of the $U_i$ are *not* equal to $\{0, 1\}$.

This means that there is a biggest index $N$ such that $U_N \neq \{0, 1\}$. The sequence $x_n$ will be contained in that neighbouthood for any $n > N$, proving convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! But as a form of proof verification, can I prove it this way: Since any open set $U$ with $x \in U$ is of the form $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} U_i$, where $U_i$ equals {0,1} for all but finitely many i, any open sets containing x, will contain other points of A other than x, hence it is a limit point?

Comment: @user90831 After some reading, I've figured out that what you have is technically the definition of limit point, I was mistaken. Yes, every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains other points, so $x$ is a limit point. The sequence definition I have in my answer is something else, but they are equivalent in spaces where closed sets are sequentially closed (so-called sequential spaces).